# Requesting multiple Bluetooth permissions in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm developing an app with connectivity which connects to a Bluetooth device with SDK 23 as compile with. I'm having problems with requesting multiple permissions for Bluetooth. This is what I have done so far:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (D)
        Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN},
                REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN},
                REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // permission was granted, yay! 
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                if (CommonData.mChatService == null)
                    setupChat();

                Toast.makeText(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this, "Permission denied for bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay!
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                if (CommonData.mChatService == null)
                    setupChat();

                Toast.makeText(MyBlueToothClientActivity.this, "Permission denied for bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Although I'm able to get the dialogue box for requesting enabling the Bluetooth, I don't get the second permission, i.e. to connect to a device. In the logcat, I get:

```
    01-01 06:41:24.334 25473-25473 E/BluetoothChat: ++ ON START ++
    01-01 06:41:24.344 25473-25473 W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
```

And since I'm not able to connect to the device, I just get stuck here. And this code works fine on Android version up to Lollipop, just causes problem on the Marshmallow version.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` are [normal permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html) and are therefore they are automatically granted. Only permissions in the [table of dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) need to requested at runtime.

However, as mentioned in the [Android 6.0 changes: Access to Hardware Identifier](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id):

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) or [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) permissions:
>
> - [WifiManager.getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())
> - [BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_FOUND)
> - [BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback))

If you're using any of those methods, you'll need to request at least `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` at runtime (as it *is* a dangerous permission).

Comment: Oh. Then do I not need to request for them? If no, how do I handle them for versions lower than Marshmallow? Also, if I needed to use other permissions like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , how to I request for them, since I might get the same error there?

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think might actually be your issue (you need the location permission for Bluetooth scanning if you target 6.0+). In any case, you can request multiple permissions at the same time (as you do), but what you can't do is call `requestPermissions()` more than once in a row.

You should just combine your if statements and call `checkSelfPermissions()` on every permission you want to request and if any of them aren't granted then request them all (the system won't prompt the user to accept permissions they've already accepted).