# Android need user explicitly give approval to turn on Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

My APP is doing the indoor location. Our solution is to scan BLE device continuously. But we encountered our first problem. After 2-3 hours, the bluetooth API can't get any result for scanning. So, we try to turn off the bluetooth and turn it on again to solve this problem. It worked for devices running on Android 6.0 and below. But for Android 7.0 and above, when we try to turn on the bluetooth by call "BluetoothAdapter.enable()", it always ask for user to give explicit approval for that, which makes my APP can't running in background without involving user.

The doc from Android says that bluetooth permission is not a dangerous permission, isn't it? Why does user need to be involved to give an approval for that?

Comment: what version of Android is your doc? Sometimes you might need to enable  a fine_access_location permission along with your bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Above the marshmallow device you need to take permission in run time from user.

```
public void onCheckingPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileMakingActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        //  initQRCodeReaderView();
        //  Utils.log("Camera AllPermission Granted . ");
        requestPermission();

        Log.i("permission", "Requesting  AllPermission");


    } else {
        Log.i("permission", "permission Granted");
        getVcardString();

        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

} 


    private void requestPermission() {


    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ProfileMakingActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "All permission are required to use this app",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
            }
        }).show();
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Requesting contacts permission. Required for this app.",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
        }
    }



    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        return;
    }

    if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "permission was granted. Now you can all contacts", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getVcardString();

    } else {
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Need Allow Permisson to access the accounts", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}

}
```

**Just call  onCheckingPermission(); in on create**

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION` in runtime at least. This answer will probably help you.

[Requesting multiple Bluetooth permissions in Android Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784663/requesting-multiple-bluetooth-permissions-in-android-marshmallow][1])

(I still have not enough points to add comments, so im posting it as answer)