# Bluetooth permissions in Android 9

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions

I'm testing Bluetooth with a Huawei Honor 8 device (Android 9).
The permissions in `manifest.xml` are registered:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

1) Why, in Android 9, when `bluetoothAdapter.enable()` is called, a request pops up for permission to turn on Bluetooth (and also to turn off)? Although this permission has already been given to the application. In the list of permissions (`Settings-Applications-My application-Rights`) there are:

- Permission to "request a connection, accept a connection, transfer
  data" (I assume this is `BLUETOOTH`)
- Permission to "start scanning devices and changing Bluetooth settings"
  (I assume this is `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`)

On a device with Android 4.4, no additional requests arise.

In order for the system to remember the issued permission, do I need to display its request using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` ?

2) Why are these 2 permissions not in the main list of permissions, but as additional permissions (you must specifically click on the Advanced button to see them)?

**UPDATE:**
If I understand correctly, all the [normal permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html) (which are BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) are often found as Additional.

Comment: check out this link   https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784732/7176189